# new Date() in aggregate $project

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For one of my collections, which must remain unix timestamp instead of isodate, I usually convert the timestamp with new Date(unix_timestamp).

Now I need the `new Date(ts)` in an aggregation. (the example is in PHP)

> '$project' => array ( 'day' => '$new Date(ts)', ...
>
> '$group' => array ( "_id" => array('day' => '$day)', ...),...

does not arrive in the results. The field "day" in the result is missing entirely.

How to get this converted within the aggregation?

Answer (score 26):

to be able to add a timestamp field from the document, you can do this, given:

```
{"ts": 1400512120100}
```

to aggregate as a date:

```
db.foo.aggregate({
   $project: {
       date: { $add: [new Date(0), "$ts"] }
   }
})
```

Comment: This helped me so much!  My timestamps are all in UTC and I wanted to convert to local time.  I was able to do it using this approach.

{$project: {dd: {$add:[new Date(0), { $subtract: [ {$multiply: ["$items.ordered", 1000]}, tzoffset ]}]}, ...

Comment: I see this works, but what is going on here? Just `> new Date(1400512120100)` results, correctly, in `ISODate("2014-05-19T15:08:40.100Z")`. But if you try using `new Date()` in the `$project` without the `$add`, you get `disallowed field type Date in object expression`. Yet clearly dates can be returned, per this example. If you try `$add: [new Date("$ts")]` in the `$project`, you get a large negative year (`ISODate("-292275055-05-16T16:47:03.192Z")`). How is `$add` handling the data types correctly and returning an `ISODate` without error?

Comment: @duozmo: I think the reason just `new Date()` does not work is that `new Date()` is only executed once, before the pipeline starts. Only the special MongoDB "aggregation operators" (like `$add`, `$trunc` etc.) will run for each value. Thus if you want to create a date during aggregation, you must use one of these operators. Since there is no operator `millisecondsToDate` in MongoDB, you must (ab)use `$add`.

Comment: Also note that `$add: [new Date(0), "$ts"]` only works because `$add` specifically supports adding milliseconds to a date.

Comment: But if I don't have time in mls

Answer (score 3):

For additional calculated fields in projection you need to use $add operator, like this:
(console example)

```
db.so.aggregate([{$project: {date: {$add: Date() }}}])
```

but it's wrong and we get a error message:

```
exception: $add does not support strings (or dates)
```

But I found a simple hack =)

```
db.so.aggregate([{$project: {date: {$substr: [Date(), 0, -1] }}}])
```

In this case we'll have expected result with dates
Also, in PHP output you can see error like this:

```
exception: disallowed field type Date in object expression (at 'date')
```

And now, solution(php 5.4 syntax):

```
$so->aggregate([
    ['$project' => ["date" => ['$substr' => [new MongoDate(), 0, -1]] ] ]
]);
```

Comment: this does not convert the field ts' value into a mongo date. It's only accepting php string or number as input, not the value from the collection itself :/

Comment: Ops, sorry) May be should to use map-reduce instead of aggregation for this case?

Comment: @KirillZorin, this is brilliant! the substr is perfect for projecting only date, dropping the time part. This is very helpful!!

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Mongo 4.0`, this can be achieved with the [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#exp._S_toDate) aggregation operator:

```
// { "ts": 1400512120100 }
db.collection.aggregate({ $project: { date: { $toDate: "$ts" } } })
// { "date": ISODate("2014-05-19T15:08:40.100Z") }
```